# cakephp fat model still undefined variable in the view action

Tags: variables, cakephp, undefined

I have created a method in my model that successfully displays the correct data when I pr($variable) to the screen. However without the print I am receiving the 'Notice (8): Undefined variable' message.

The model in question 'industry' has many 'news and events'.

What I'm trying to do in the view for a specific industry is display news that is of two different conditions. One type of news is news.type = highlight(displaying just one highlight story), and the second is a list of active stories.

This is the method in my model.

```
    // industry highlight news
public function getHighlightNews() {
    $newsHeadline = $this->News->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('News.type' => 'highlight','News.active' => 'yes'),
        'limit' => 1,
        'recursive' => 0,
        'fields' => array(
            'News.slug', 
            'News.title', 
            'News.date', 
            'News.imgPathThumb',
            'News.alt_tag',
            'News.id',
            'News.caption',
            'News.body'
            ),
        ));

     return $newsHeadline;
    }


    public function getNewsList() {
    $newslist = $this->News->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('News.active = "Yes"','News.industry_id = 1'),
        'limit' => 4,
        'recursive' => 0,
        'fields' => array(
            'News.slug', 
            'News.title', 
            'News.date', 
            'News.industry_id', 
            'News.imgPathThumb',
            'News.alt_tag',
            'News.id',
            'News.caption',
            'News.body'
            ),
        ));

     return $newslist;
    }
```

And this is what is in my industry controller. I've created similar model methods for the news list and event lists.

```
    public function view($id = null) {
    $this->layout='default';    
    $this->Industry->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Industry->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid industry'));
    }               

    $eventlist = $this->Industry->getEventsList($id);   
    $newslist = $this->Industry->getNewsList($id);  
    $highlights = $this->Industry->getHighlightNews($id);

    //pr($newslist); die;   
    $this->set('eventlist', $eventlist, 'newslist', $newslist, 'highlights', $highlights);
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="first articles">
 <?php  foreach ($highlights as $highlight): ?>
   <h1><?php echo $highlight['Industry']['title']; ?></h1>
   <p><?php echo $highlight['Industry']['body']; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </p>
</div><!-- /articles -->
```

the message I get in the view is:

Notice (8): Undefined variable: highlights [APP\View\Industries\view.ctp, line 12]

Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Industries\view.ctp, line 12]

I suspect it's something small I'm overlooking.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting variables doesn't work like that. You need to change this:

```
$this->set('eventlist', $eventlist, 'newslist', $newslist, 'highlights', $highlights);
```

To this:

```
$this->set('eventlist', $eventlist);
$this->set('newslist', $newslist); 
$this->set('highlights', $highlights);
```

Or this:

```
$this->set(compact('eventlist','newslist','highlights'));
```

Comment: thanks Nick. I suspected it was related to how 'set' and variables work but didn't find the answer.

Comment: thanks Nick. I suspected it was related to how 'set' and variables work. After I made your changes I don't see any results. But when I debug each variable the correct data is returned. I think it's related to the routing. For each industry, I've added a route as follows: Router::connect('/industryName1',array
  ('controller' => 'industries', 'action' => 'view', 1)); Since there will only be four industries on this site, I wanted their names/slugs to be in the link to each view. I'm not sure what is the better way to do this and ensure each variable in the view populates with data.

Comment: Did you confirm that the routing works correctly? I mean, you end up at the correct function with the correct variable data? And after that, is it rendering the correct view file?

Comment: Using the route I mentioned above, the route did go to the Industries view and record number 1. But, if I go to record #2 it doesn't work since only record number 1 data is returned. Looks like only record #1 data is passed. And after your changes nothing shows unless I debug the variable.

Comment: So it's not getting to the correct view file probably. Have you tried echoing something out from the view.ctp, to see if you get there? Btw, I just noticed that you're not naming your controller correctly, it should be IndustryController, per Cake naming conventions. Not following it could cause weird issues sometimes.